# Writing an object's attributes to a sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite

In my application I have a class `User` and the class has `id, ip, os` as attributes or values - not sure which one is the correct term.

I fetch the data needed and write it to a dictionary through `json.loads()`, for example:

```
data = {'id': '111', 'ip': '127.0.0.1', 'os': 'windows'}
```

I use the data to create a new User i.e.

```
user1 = User(111, "127.0.0.", "windows")
```

I have a database with a table `user` that stores the same attributes/values and I want to store that user in the database.

So is there a way to store the user in the databse without getting the data from the dictionary again?

Comment: Are you using sqlalchemy or are you interfacing directly to sqlite?

Comment: @junnytony directly to sqlite, haven't heard of sqlalchemy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending @junnytony's answer, you can retrieve object from dictionary, make object to dictionary using simple method.

Example:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, id=None, ip=None, os=None, input_dict=None):
        if input_dict:
            self.from_dict(input_dict)
        else:
            self.id = id
            self.ip = ip
            self.os = os

    def from_dict(self, input_dict):
        self.id = input_dict.get('id')
        self.ip = input_dict.get('ip')
        self.os = input_dict.get('os')

    def to_dict(self):
        return {'id': self.id, 'ip': self.ip, 'os': self.os}

    def __repr__(self):
        return "id: {0}, ip: {1}, os: {2}".format(self.id, self.ip, self.os)

user1 = User(1, "127.0.0.1", "windows")
dict1 = user1.to_dict()
dict1['id'] = 2
user2 = User(input_dict=dict1)

print user1
# id: 1, ip: 127.0.0.1, os: windows

print user2
# id: 2, ip: 127.0.0.1, os: windows
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to get the data from the dictionary again? If you want to store your `User` object why not just write a function that accesses `User.id`, `User.ip` and `User.os` and passes it to the Sqlite interface?

If that solution doesn't work for you: you can create a method in your `User` object that converts the objects attributes to a dictionary...something like `User.to_dict()`. There is already the inbuilt `__dict__` attribute of every object but the issue with using that directly is that it may contain other parameters that you don't want to push to the database layer.

Example:

```
Class User(object):
    def __init__(id, ip, os):
        self.id = id
        self.ip = ip
        self.os = os

    def to_dict():
        return {'id': self.id, 'ip': self.ip, 'os': self.os}
```

Comment: I am pretty much beginner at python and still learning the ins and outs. Thank you for the suggestion